# Авторизация на сайте через requests Python3

Tags: python, requests

Прошу помощи в написании куска кода с авторизацией на сайте https://binomo.com средствами requests python3. Знаю что надо найти post запрос отправляемый браузером при авторизации, но вот его то я и не могу найти. Смотрю через средства разработчика в Firefox и Opera. Пока имею следующее:

```
import requests

data = {'email':'11111@yandex.ru', 'password':'111111'}
login = "1111111@yandex.ru"#логин
pass_ = "1111111"#пароль
Url = "https://binomo.com/ru/account"#ссылка на сайт
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'}#эмитация живого пользователя
r = requests.get(Url,  headers = headers, data = data)#отправка запроса на сайт
print(r.status_code)

session = requests.Session()
respons = session.get(Url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(respons.status_code)

res = requests.post("https://binomo.com/api/profile?device=web&locale=ru", headers = headers, data = data)
print(res.text)
print(res)
```

это мой первый опыт в этом направлении, прошу не пинать!))

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/ / `r = requests.get(Url,  headers = headers, auto=(login, pass_))` а так? Да и делайте все в рамкой сессии -- наверняка после авторизации придут к вам куки, которые нужно будет передавать

Comment: Не смотрел тот сайт, но учтите, что существуют всяческие механики (вроде CSFR токенов) препятствующие POST-запросам исходящим не с самого сайта. [Подробнее здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Межсайтовая_подделка_запроса). Если такое есть на том сайте, то через `requests` будет непросто зайти. Поэтому лучше использовать открытые АПИ (например, Вк АПИ или чего-то такого же популярного), особенно в качестве первого опыта.

Comment: Посмотрел сайт. Тот при авторизации шлет ajax POST запрос на https://binomo.com/api/sign_in А данными у него будут JSON: `{"email":"1111111@yandex.ru","password":"1111111","remember_me":true}`. Так что, открывайте страницу сайта, на ней открывайте инструменты разработчика (кнопка F12) и смотрите какие запросы идут :) А в вашем коде нужно не `get`, а `post` вызывать. Вместо `data=data` писать `json=data`